# ThinkPad x1 YOGA and Samsung 970 EVO Plus NVMe M.2 compatibility

Tags: hard-drive, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, nvme, samsung-ssd

I need a new internal HDD for my Lenovo **[ThinkPad x1 YOGA** **2**nd generation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0722HFQ8D) with an i7 processor. Is the **[Samsung 970 EVO Plus](https://www.amazon.de/Samsung-MZ-V7S1T0BW-Plus-Interne-3-500/dp/B07MBQPQ62)** NVMe M.2 (1 TB, MZ-V7S1T0BW) compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is compatible. See [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/X1-Yoga-2nd-gen-SSD-upgrade-really-could-use-some-guidance-assistance/m-p/4288695?page=3#4295729)